# Rails and PostgreSQL join models in search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to create a search query that searches two models. I have a model called `equipment` which belongs_to `user` which has_one `extended_profile`.

In the `extended_profile` there is a field called `city`. The `equipment` table has all the information about the equipment. When the user types in a search query, I want to search some fields of `equipment` and also the `city` field of the extended_profile belonging to the user who owns the equipment. I've got it working as for searching the fields of `equipment` but don't know how to join the other model in the query. Here's what I got so far:

```
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.search(search)
   if search
     where("title @@ :q or make @@ :q or model @@ :q", q: search)
   else
     scoped
   end
  end

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :extended_profile
end

class ExtendedProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Any help on how to get `extended_profiles` joined in the search would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is general idea how this could be done, using named scopes. Please note, that I made some assumptions, and the following code may not be a drop-in solution, but should point you in the right direction.

```
 scope :with_all_joins, joins(%{left outer join "users" on "users"."id" = "equipments"."user_id"
    left outer join "extended_profiles" on "extended_profile"."user_id" = "users"."id"})

  scope :with_keyword, lambda { |q| with_all_joins.where('lower("extended_profiles"."city") like :keyword or
                                                          lower("equipments"."title") like :keyword', {:keyword => "%#{q.downcase}%"}) }
```

Then you can call it like `Equipment.with_keyword('something')`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```rb
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :user_extended_profile, through: :user, source: :extended_profile

  # Assuming city is passed via search[:city]
  def self.search(search)
   if search
     city = search.delete(:city)

     relation = where("title @@ :q or make @@ :q or model @@ :q", q: search)

     if city
       relation = relation
         .joins(:user_extended_profile)
         .where('extended_profiles.city @@ ?', city)
   else
     scoped
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying it out now, one thing I am not clear about: What does city = search.delete(:city) do?

Comment: It is the `Hash#delete` method: it deletes the `:city` key from `search` returning its value; I'm using it here in order to extracting the city, but just because I suppose that search is an hash... instead, maybe you pass city in another way, like f.e. as argument, and you don't need `city = search.delete(:city)`

Comment: Now I'm noticing that you are treating `search` as string, so my suspect that you want to pass it as an argument increases... how d oyou want to pass the city to this method?

Comment: Well, it is actually just one simple search box, where the user must be able to type in a city OR for example an equipment type. So the city isn't passed separately... For example I type in "Amsterdam" and I get all the equipment with `city LIKE "AMSTERDAM"`, but when I type in "Waveboard", I get all the boards with `"wave board"` in the description. Please tell me if I'm not clear enough, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ok but you are talking about the controller, instead we are in the model context, so the controller is not relevant... I mean, it is relevant but just for convenience reasons, since the controller actually will call the model method someway: so the way to pass the city value to `self.search` is up to you. Was I clear?

Comment: Okey I'm no passing the city separately through search[:city] and the code runs without errors, But I get 0 search results...

Comment: Well, debug it :) catch the input value, call the method inside `rails console` using the input value, take a look to `Equipment.search(input_value).to_sql` and find out what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip! I printed out the sql statement: `"SELECT \"equipment\".* FROM \"equipment\" INNER JOIN \"users\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"equipment\".\"user_id\" INNER JOIN \"extended_profiles\" ON \"extended_profiles\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" WHERE (title @@ 'JP' or make @@ 'JP' or model @@ 'JP') AND (extended_profiles.city @@ 'JP')"` And I think it's almost perfect, except for the `AND` which must be `OR`, how do I go about this?

Comment: Refactor the relation in order to put the city where together with the other wheres, or take a look at [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel). Sorry but I can't help you further, I feel like I'm doing your homework for you